# What is a word for something that isn't a word?

Tags: single-word-requests

I have been looking for a word that means "something that isn't a word". I'm trying to say that most words refer to things that aren't words (ex. the word pencil refers to something that isn't a word)

Comment: We use the coding 'pencil', a well understood _word_, to focus someone's mind on the **referent**, a particular or a generalised sharpened stick of wood containing graphite or some other marking solid, used for writing / drawing. One is reminded of Magritte's 'This is not a pipe' (actually pointing out that the label was attached to a painting). One could argue that 'This' is actually a word rather than a painting, even translated into French. // If you want 'word whose referent is a non-word', this is 99.9%+ of words and won't have a term. The exceptions include 'adjective', 'anagram', ...

Comment: 'synonym', 'homophone', 'keyword', 'eponym', name', hypernym', 'loanword', 'malapropism' ... too diverse a collection to have a descriptor other than say the contrived  '_word_-words'.  '_Non-word_-words' isn't idiomatic either.